# Can't get users email in Rest api used parse dashboard

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was used parse dashboard package with parse.query and get users details.
i have get all users record and parse.query to used, i getting the response but email key can't show each and every used record , the email field is show parse dashboard and mongodb table.

If your know that solution so please give me help. blow my code

```
var fetchUserWithIdentifier = function (userIdentifier) {
        let query = new Parse.Query(User)
        query.equalTo(User.Field.objectId, userIdentifier)
        return query.first()
        };


    class User extends Parse.Object {
    /**
     * @return {string}
     */
    get firstName() {
        return this.get(User.Field.firstName)
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} firstName
     */
    set firstName(firstName) {
        this.set(User.Field.firstName, firstName)
    }

    /**
     * @return {string}
     */
    get email() {
        return this.get(User.Field.email)
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} email
     */
    set email(email) {
        this.set(User.Field.email, email)
    }

    /**
     * @return {string}
     */
    get googleId() {
        return this.get(User.Field.googleId)
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} googleId
     */
    set googleId(googleId) {
        this.set(User.Field.googleId, googleId)
    }

    /**
     * @return {string}
     */
    get facebookId() {
        return this.get(User.Field.facebookId)
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} facebookId
     */
    set facebookId(facebookId) {
        this.set(User.Field.facebookId, facebookId)
    }

    /**
     * @return {string}
     */
    get facebookEmail() {
        return this.get(User.Field.facebookEmail)
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} facebookEmail
     */
    set facebookEmail(facebookEmail) {
        this.set(User.Field.facebookEmail, facebookEmail)
    }

    /**
     * @return {boolean} 
     */
    get isAnonymous() {
        return this.get(User.Field.isAnonymous)
    }

    /**
     * @param {boolean} isAnonymous
     */
    set isAnonymous(isAnonymous) {
        this.set(User.Field.isAnonymous, isAnonymous)
    }


    /**
    * @return {number} 
    */
    get deviceToken() {
        return this.get(User.Field.deviceToken)
    }

    /**
     * @param {number} deviceToken
     */
    set deviceToken(deviceToken) {
        this.set(User.Field.deviceToken, deviceToken)
    }

    /**
    * @return {boolean} 
    */
    get isActivityVisible() {
        return this.get(User.Field.isActivityVisible)
    }

    /**
     * @param {boolean} friendActivity
     */
    set isActivityVisible(isActivityVisible) {
        this.set(User.Field.isActivityVisible, isActivityVisible)
    }



    /**
    * @return {string} 
    */
    get deviceType() {
        return this.get(User.Field.deviceType)
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} deviceType
     */
    set deviceType(deviceType) {
        this.set(User.Field.deviceType, deviceType)
    }


    /**
     * @return {string}
     */
    get inviterIdentifier() {
        return this.get(User.Field.inviterIdentifier)
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} inviterIdentifier
     */
    set inviterIdentifier(inviterIdentifier) {
        this.set(User.Field.inviterIdentifier, inviterIdentifier)
    }

    /**
     * @return {MeditationTime}
     */
    get meditationTime() {
        return this.get(User.Pointer.meditationTime)
    }

    /**
     * @param {MeditationTime} meditationTime
     */
    set meditationTime(meditationTime) {
        this.set(User.Pointer.meditationTime, meditationTime)
    }

    /**
     * @return {Parse.Relation<User, Goal>}
     */
    get goals() {
        return this.relation(User.Relation.goals)
    }

    /**
     * @return {Parse.Relation<User, UserMeditationCourse>}
     */
    get meditationCourses() {
        return this.relation(User.Relation.meditationCourses)
    }

    /**
     * @return {Parse.Relation<User, Friendship>}
     */
    get friendships() {
        return this.relation(User.Relation.friendships)
    }

    /**
     * @return {Parse.Relation<User, UserGroupSession>}
     */
    get groupSessions() {
        return this.relation(User.Relation.groupSessions)
    }

        constructor() {
            super('_User');
        }
    }

    User.SocialType = class SocialType extends Enum { }

    User.SocialType.initEnum(['facebook',
        'google']);

    User.Field = {
    objectId: 'objectId',
    email: 'email',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    createdAt: 'createdAt',
    updatedAt: 'updatedAt',
    firstName: 'firstName',
    // lastName: 'lastName',
    googleId: 'googleId',
    facebookId: 'facebookId',
    facebookEmail: 'facebookEmail',
    avatarPath: 'avatarPath',
    isAnonymous: 'isAnonymous',
    socialType: 'socialType',
    inviterIdentifier: 'inviterIdentifier',
    deviceToken: 'deviceToken',
    deviceType: 'deviceType',
    isActivityVisible: 'isActivityVisible',
}
    User.Pointer = {
        meditationTime: 'meditationTime'
    }

    User.Relation = {
        goals: 'goals',
        meditationCourses: 'meditationCourses',
        socialAccounts: 'socialAccounts',
        friendships: 'friendships',
        groupSessions: 'groupSessions'
    }

    module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var fetchUserWithIdentifier = function (userIdentifier) {
        let query = new Parse.Query(User)
        query.equalTo(User.Field.objectId, userIdentifier)
        return query.first({ useMasterKey: true })
        };
```

Comment: I was used the useMasterKey but  not getting user email.

Comment: try replacing  let query = new Parse.Query(User) by  let query = new Parse.Query(_User)